# Why are my row names dropped and how to avoid it?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I want to replace a certain string by another in a data frame
here is a sample code:

```
table_ex <- data.frame(row.names = c("row 1", "row 2", "row 3"))
table_ex$year1 <- 3:1
table_ex$year2 <- c("NaN", 5, "NaN %")
table_ex$year3 <- c("NaN %", 7, "NaN %")

remove_symb <- function(yolo){stringr::str_replace(yolo, 'NaN %|NaN', '')}
table_ex <- mutate_all(table_ex, funs(remove_symb))
```

Doing the above is dropping my rownnames.  I understand I could use a lapply function, but I'm wondering why are the row names dropped.  Is it because of the `str_replace` functions or the `mutate_all` functions?  And how should I prevent that?

Comment: `dplyr` and `data.table` resets the row names to NULL

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I didn't know that.  I'm wondering what is the rational for that.  Maybe for efficiency when doing computation on the df?

Comment: Having some attributes could reduce the performance

Comment: dplyr discourages storing variables in row names because they can easily get messed up. You can use `tibble::rownames_to_column` to incorporate them as a proper variable, if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we need to keep the row names, loop through the columns and assign it back to the original data and to keep the structure intact use `[]`.

```
table_ex[] <- lapply(table_ex, remove_symb)
table_ex
#      year1 year2 year3
#row 1     3            
#row 2     2     5     7
#row 3     1
```

---

Using `dplyr` or `data.table` will change the row names to numeric sequence, but with `[]`, we can still change it to the original row names

```
table_ex[] <- mutate_all(table_ex, funs(remove_symb))
```

Comment: It works like a charm.  I knew I could access rows or columns using the [3, ] or [ , 3] but I never thought about using the [ ] on its own.  Thank you.

Comment: Any idea how `[]` preserves these unlike `mutate_`?

Comment: @NelsonGon In the `mutate_all`, we don't need the `[]`, as it is already a data.frame/tbl_df.  with `base r`, the `lapply` returns a `list` of vectors and data.frame is a list of vectors with the dimenssion attributes and other things.  So, when we use `[]`, it is directing the output on the rhs to have the same structure (dims) as the lhs

Comment: @akrun This is great! Any idea of how to use the `[]` trick in a pipeline?

Comment: @DanChaltiel DId you meant in a list of data.frames?  If that is the case `lst1 <-lapply(lst1, function(dat) {dat[] <- lapply(dat, remove_symb); dat})`

Comment: @akrun more like in `table_ex %>% mutate_all(remove_symb)`

Comment: @DanChaltiel  If you are looking for a tidyverse operation.  `table_ex %<>% mutate_all(remove_symb)` the `%<>%` is from `magrittr`