# How to change value in one data frame based on the other data frame?

Tags: r

Hi， I need your help to change the values in one data frame based on the other one. For example, there are data frame A and B. A has more species than B, but with the same samples. Now I want to change the value in data frame A to: 
1) "No" for the species(**values**) that are not in data frame B or are na in data frame B for each sample;
2) "Yes" for the species that are not "NA" in data frame B.

The real data has many species.

Data frame A

```
       species1 species2    species3    species4    species5    species6
sample1 0.5       0.3          0          0.5          0           0.5
sample2 0.6       0.5          0          0.5          0.5         0
sample3 0.7       0.7          0          0            0           0
sample4 0.8       0.9          0.5        0.5          0           0
sample5 0.9       1.1          0.5        0.3          0           0.5
```

Data frame B

```
        species2    species5    species3
sample1   NA          0.3         NA
sample2   NA          0.5         NA
sample3   0.7         NA          0.2
sample4   0.8         0.9         0.5
sample5   NA          NA          0.5
```

The expected result likes below:

```
       species1 species2    species3    species4    species5    species6
sample1 No        No          No           No          Yes         No
sample2 No        No          No           No          Yes         No
sample3 No        Yes         Yes          No          No          No
sample4 No        Yes         Yes          No          Yes         No
sample5 No        No          Yes          No          No          No
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I still don't get why Species 3 is yes yes yes, are you matching values or some other criteria? Given only two values exist in both data sets, shouldn't there be two yes values?

Comment: The question has been updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr`, `base` and `purrr`:

```
    library(dplyr)
rep_at <- setdiff(names(df1),names(df2))
df1 %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(rep_at),function(x) x="No") -> df1
replacements <- as.data.frame(purrr::map(df2,function(y) 
    ifelse(is.na(y), "no","yes")),
    stringsAsFactors=F)
 df1[,match(names(replacements),names(df1))] <- replacements
  df1
```

Result:

```
    species1 species2 species3 species4 species5 species6
1       No       no       no       No      yes       No
2       No       no       no       No      yes       No
3       No      yes      yes       No       no       No
4       No      yes      yes       No      yes       No
5       No       no      yes       No       no       No
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, may I ask why the row names changed to the number after the step of mutate_at?

Comment: Been several hours, don't remember them changing. Could you please elaborate how they changed?

Comment: @Bio_farmer You mean sample1,sample2,etc?

Comment: Currently can't access my PC. You can solve that by setting the result bask to `[]` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968821/why-are-my-row-names-dropped-and-how-to-avoid-it

Comment: In addition, may I ask when I transfer the "replacement", why is the space in column names changed to "."? How to stop it?

Comment: Could you paste the output of `names(replacement)[1:5]` here? I honestly can't figure out  without seeing the output because I didn't get this issue.

Comment: Hi, as there is space in the species name in the real data, for example, species 1, when transforming the "replacement" to data frame, "species 1" will be changed "species.1". How can I still keep the space in the name of "replacement"?

Comment: You can do this after the transformation. `names(replacement) <- gsub("\\.","\\s",names(replacement))`

Comment: Thank you. When I run the last command for my data, there is error : Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , match(names(replacements), names(df1)),  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames.

Comment: I cannot know, make sure that both data set names are of the same structure and there are no more `NA`s in your data. I cannot know honestly. Only work(ed) basing on the provided data.

Comment: Thank you very much. All the errors have been solved. The names of the two data set are not totally consistent. Thank you again.